# MySQL error #1089 while creating database

Tags: mysql

I am creating a database it keeps on giving me error:

```
CREATE TABLE `pgdavplacments`.`drive` ( `drive_id` INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
`drive_name` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL , 
`drive_date` DATE NOT NULL , 
`drive_time` TIME NOT NULL , 
`drive_info` VARCHAR(8000) NOT NULL , 
`eligibility1` INT(5) NOT NULL , 
`eligibility2` INT(5) NOT NULL , 
`eligibility3` INT(5) NOT NULL , 
PRIMARY KEY (`drive_id`(1000))) 
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE `pgdavplacments`.`drive` (
    `drive_id` INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `drive_name` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    `drive_date` DATE NOT NULL,
    `drive_time` TIME NOT NULL,
    `drive_info` VARCHAR(8000) NOT NULL,
    `eligibility1` INT(5) NOT NULL,
    `eligibility2` INT(5) NOT NULL,
    `eligibility3` INT(5) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`drive_id` )
)  ENGINE=INNODB;
```

You can try above query.

Comment: It helped. This means that I must not fix the value when using auto_increment?

Comment: Yes it is..
But still i didn't get why you put `1000` at `PRIMARY KEY (drive_id(1000))` line?

Comment: @Bhanusingh : if you want to set auto increment value, then write something like this at the end `ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=100`